# Splash screen for jQuery Mobile web-app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to do a splash-screen for web-site based on jQuery Mobile and ASP.Net MVC. My problem is that I can't really change the navigation structure, because all the controllers are used in the desktop version of the site. Mobile side of the site only has separate *.Mobile.cshtml views and that has to follow the same navigation conventions as the desktop site.

What I'm trying to do is create a jQuery mobile "page" like this in the "home" page:

```
@if (ViewBag.ShowSplash!= null && ViewBag.ShowSplash == true) 
{
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="splash">
        <div id="splash_container">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/splash_logo.png")" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        // once we display splash screen, give it 4 seconds and load main container
        $(document).on('pageinit', '#splash', function () {
            var hideSplash = function () {
                $.mobile.changePage($("#container"));
            };
            setTimeout(hideSplash, 4000);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Where `ViewBag.ShowSplash` is set in the controller, checking if cookie is set on the first load.
The problem I face is the splash screen keeps coming back whenever I go back to the home screen, even if cookie is set and `ViewBag.ShowSplash` is null in the controller. I guess JQM is caching all the pages and `#splash` is stuck there indefinitely.

To fix JQM caching I'm removing the `#splash` container like this:

```
// Once main container is loaded, remove splash page-container so we can't come back to that thing again. Ever.
$(document).on('pageshow', '#container', function () {
    $('#splash').remove();
});
```

This kinda works for splash, but breaks other things, like navigation.

I wonder if there is an easier way to do a splash screen in JQM and if not, is there a way to tell JQM to never come back to a certain page?